# Showing detailed data of of selected cell at DataTable

Tags: flutter, dart

I've the below code that is fetching data from url and display it in a DataTable.

I want to add more functionality to my code so that more details popingup based on the selected id or field, for example:

- If I pressed the line, I need to read the hidden ID number

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: HomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

Future<List<List<dynamic>>> fetchUserData() async {
  final request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQvf9tp4-fETDJbC-HRmRKvVFAXEAGO4lrYPpVeiYkB6nqqXdSs3CjX0eBMvjIoEeX9_qU6K2RWmzVk/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv'));
  final response = await request.close();
  List<List<dynamic>> rowsAsListOfValues;
  await for (final csvString in response.transform(const Utf8Decoder())) {
    rowsAsListOfValues = const CsvToListConverter().convert(csvString);
  }
  return rowsAsListOfValues;
}

class _AppState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<List<dynamic>> rowsAsListOfValues;
  ScrollController _controller;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    rowsAsListOfValues = await fetchUserData();
    super.setState(() {}); // to update widget data
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = ScrollController();
    _controller = new ScrollController()..addListener(_scrollListener);
  }

  void _scrollListener() {
    if (_controller.position.extentAfter <= 0.0 &&
        _controller.offset >= _controller.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_controller.position.outOfRange) {
      print("call fetch method again");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            rowsAsListOfValues == null
                ? Text("Loading data...")
                : Text(
              '', // $rowsAsListOfValues
            ),
            rowsAsListOfValues == null
                ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                : DataTable(
                columns: const <DataColumn>[
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text(
                      'City',
                      style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text(
                      'Branches',
                      style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
                rows: List.generate(rowsAsListOfValues.length - 1, (index) {
                  return DataRow(
                    cells: <DataCell>[
                      // DataCell(Text('${rowsAsListOfValues[index + 1][0]}')), // Index
                      DataCell(Text('${rowsAsListOfValues[index + 1][1]}')),  // city
                      DataCell(Text('${rowsAsListOfValues[index + 1][2]}')),  // branch
                    ],
                  );
                })),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My dat astructure is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it using `onSelectChanged` as below:

```dart
showCheckboxColumn: false, // <-- this is important
```

and

```dart
rows: List.generate(rowsAsListOfValues.length - 1, (index) {
    return DataRow(
        onSelectChanged: (bool selected) {
            if (selected) {
                print('index-selected: ${rowsAsListOfValues[index + 1][0]}');
            }
        },
        cells: <DataCell>[
             // DataCell(Text('${rowsAsListOfValues[index + 1][0]}')), // Index
             DataCell(Text('${rowsAsListOfValues[index + 1][1]}')),  // city
             DataCell(Text('${rowsAsListOfValues[index + 1][2]}')),  // branch
        ],
   );
}),
```

And the updated code is:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: HomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

Future<List<List<dynamic>>> fetchUserData() async {
  final request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQvf9tp4-fETDJbC-HRmRKvVFAXEAGO4lrYPpVeiYkB6nqqXdSs3CjX0eBMvjIoEeX9_qU6K2RWmzVk/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv'));
  final response = await request.close();
  List<List<dynamic>> rowsAsListOfValues;
  await for (final csvString in response.transform(const Utf8Decoder())) {
    rowsAsListOfValues = const CsvToListConverter().convert(csvString);
  }
  return rowsAsListOfValues;
}

class _AppState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<List<dynamic>> rowsAsListOfValues;
  // ScrollController _controller;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    rowsAsListOfValues = await fetchUserData();
    super.setState(() {}); // to update widget data
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   // _controller = ScrollController();
   // _controller = new ScrollController()..addListener(_scrollListener);
  }
/*
  void _scrollListener() {
    if (_controller.position.extentAfter <= 0.0 &&
        _controller.offset >= _controller.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_controller.position.outOfRange) {
      print("call fetch method again");
    }
  } */

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            rowsAsListOfValues == null
                ? Text("Loading data...")
                : Text(
              '', // $rowsAsListOfValues
            ),
            rowsAsListOfValues == null
                ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                : DataTable(
                showCheckboxColumn: false, // <-- this is important
                columns: const <DataColumn>[
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text(
                      'City',
                      style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text(
                      'Branches',
                      style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
                rows: List.generate(rowsAsListOfValues.length - 1, (index) {
                  return DataRow(
                    onSelectChanged: (bool selected) {
                      if (selected) {
                        print('index-selected: ${rowsAsListOfValues[index + 1][0]}');
                      }
                    },
                    cells: <DataCell>[
                      // DataCell(Text('${rowsAsListOfValues[index + 1][0]}')), // Index
                      DataCell(Text('${rowsAsListOfValues[index + 1][1]}')),  // city
                      DataCell(Text('${rowsAsListOfValues[index + 1][2]}')),  // branch
                    ],
                  );
                }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```